# Minecraft forestry multiple arboretum multifarms cannot work at the same time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I have two of the largest size multifarms set up as arboretums to generate saplings for biofuel production. They are both set up correctly and have all resources piped in through thermal expansion tesseracts when they are low.

Both of these work fine, but the problem is that when I have them both put on at the same time, only one farm will recognize the farmland, and the other will shut itself down claiming that there is no land to lay soil on.

This is not correct, because I have had both of them working without any changes by themselves, but for some reason they cannot both run at the same time. Turning one off and leaving it as an intact farm does not correct the problem, however removing a couple farm blocks and restarting seems to switch it over to the other farm, but then the previous one cannot be re-enabled unless I do this again the other way.

Is this a bug? Or do I need to use different types of farmland bed on each? I am using smooth sandstone on both, at the third layer from the bottom of the farms, and I also have a wheat farm with stone brick farmland bedding which seems to be unaffected. The farms are next to each other on the same vertical plane with about a four block buffer between the two. I need both farms going to produce enough saplings for biofuel, as I have a rather large liquid fuel steam boiler setup generating power for the entire world (energy tesseracts).

I currently have about 2.5m fuel refined and the system automatically switches over to biofuel when regular fuel reserves run out, but I will need the biofuel system to be functional within about 4 days unless I find another huge oil reserve somewhere, and it currently only outputs roughly half of what I need to keep everything going by itself. I've spent about five hours online trying to find an answer to why this is happening and have come up with nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of forestry are you using?

Comment: MC 1.4.7, Forestry 2.0.0.11, Forge 6.6.2.534

Comment: Is this bug still relevant to the current version?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem temporarily by switching one farm to regular bricks. This is still apparently a bug, I'll go file a bug report for Sengir to see, there's no reason why multiple farms should not be able to use the same farmland, as this drastically limits the number of functional farms you could have. If anyone else has the same issue, try changing one of the multifarm farmlands to a block type not used in other identical farms until Sengir releases a patch.

EDIT: This only temporarily fixed the problem. Within 20 minutes it again didn't recognize the farmland, despite the bricks. Will have to figure out another solution, as I can't be running back to the farm to change out the blocks every 20 mins.